# Множественный вызов функций

Tags: javascript

Пробую делать сайт вообще без обновлений страницы. Главная функция mainController() подгружает  аджаксом (аяксом?) контент; в этом контенте есть ссылка, по которой с помощью  другой функции (при выполнении условия )вызывается опять же mainController(). Вопрос такой - не будут ли эти множественные вызовы функций из функций засорять стек функций и перегружать ОЗУ? Ведь функции ничего не возвращают (процедуры), а только по некоторому условию вызывают другую функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко, то - нет, не будет.

Чуть более развернуто.

> в этом контенте есть ссылка

Тогда вызов `mainController` возможен только после клика(e.g. event'a), рекурсии здесь нет,
нет рекурсии - нет описанной вами проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Шанс словить `stack overflow` при таком раскладе есть. Другое дело, что для этого, в зависимости от браузера, может понадобиться несколько тысяч рекурсивных вызовов. Лучше всего избегать такой ситуации. Если рекурсивный вызов идёт в самом конце функции, то можно попробовать вызывать функцию через `setTimeout`. Но это уже извращение. Постарайтесь пересмотреть свою архитектуру таким образом, чтобы не нужно было вызывать функцию рекурсивно.